# Why does vuejs replicates its v-model data when the v-model is referenced within a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-model

In the following code:

#### JS

```js
const App = {
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    items: Array.from({length: 50}, (x, i) => i+1).map(i => ({
      id: i ,
      name: `Item ${i}`,
      subtitle: `Subtitle ${i}`
    }))
  }),
  computed: {
    parsedItems() {
      this.selected;
      return this.items.map(item => ({
        someValue: 3,
        ...item
      }));
    }
  }
}


new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### HTML

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    {{selected}}
    <v-container>

        <v-virtual-scroll
          :items="parsedItems"
          :item-height="65"
          height="500"
        >
          <template v-slot="{ item, index }">
           <v-list-item-group
             v-model="selected"
             multiple
           >
            <v-list-item :key="item.id" :value="item">
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-checkbox
                  :input-value="selected.includes(item.id)"
                  color="primary"
                />
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  Index: {{ index }} {{ item.name }}
                </v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>
                  {{ item.subtitle }}
                </v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
           </v-list-item-group>
          </template>
        </v-virtual-scroll>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

When either of the checkboxes i checked or unchecked - the `selected` v-model always adds up another instance though it previously contains one already.

Removing `this.selected;` (line 16 in the Codepen below) fixes the issue.

I suspect that `this.selected`  is somehow dereferences its own values and then can't validate the appearance of previously selected items.

Here's a Codepen with the issue at hand: https://codepen.io/MichaelKatz/pen/vYXXdgb

In my real-world scenario, I need to filter and manipulate items within the list, according to previously made selections (i.e remove / re-add items).
I do it by using a computed `item` property which derives its content from a previously selected items, from the `selected` v-model and my current solution will require me to `JSON.stringify` all of my objects, essentially making them value-based strings to keep things in check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like accessing a v-model while filtering the items it refers to, creates a de-reference of the objects within it.

The best solution I could come up with was adding an additional computed property which will contain the logic involving `this.selected`.

It has indeed solved the issue for me.

```js
  computed: {
    parsedItems() {
      return this.items.map(item => ({
        someValue: 3,
        ...item
      }));
    },
    filteredItems() { // adding another computed property while using this.selected
      this.selected;
      return this.parsedItems;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `v-model` does not seem to work with Objects

```
<v-list-item :key="item.id" :value="item">    <!-- change this -->
<v-list-item :key="item.id" :value="item.id"> <!-- into this   -->
```

And create a new computed property to "hydrate" those ids:

```
selectedItems() {
  return this.selected.map(id => this.parsedItems.find(x => x.id === id))
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/ExggEpq)

Comment: If `this.selected` will be used to filter data - it will cause the call stack to exceed its maximum for lists bigger than a 100 or so.
It will also cause an immediate performance decrease for every item added and for the initial calculation of `selectedItems`.
See my performant solution below.

Answer (score -1):

From my perspective, the problem is you have used the `multiple` props, which will allow multiple selections.

```
      <template v-slot="{ item, index }">
       <v-list-item-group
         v-model="selected"
         multiple
       >
```

Simply removing it will solve your problem.